# Java replaceAll to replace special characters

Tags: java

I am looking for a snippet in java that replaces the

```
 "..", "/" or "\" or ":" - FileSeperator characters with
 ""
```

in a fileName property  passed from UI. This should be OS independent. 
Also I dont want to remove the "single dot", only "two dots"

Currently i wrote a snippet

```
private static void filter(){
    // should not remove the Single Dot
    String fileName = "/user/../142552/ReportFile.txt"      
    fileName = fileName.replaceAll("[/|\\|..|:|]","");
    System.out.println("fileName " + fileName); 
}
```

Output

```
fileName user142552ReportFiletxt
```

Expected Output

```
fileName user142552ReportFile.txt
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Does your code work or not? If it doesn't, then explain what the problem is.

Comment: your method removes separators from the original input successfully. user142552 is the output and I don't understand what is the meaning of this output, what will you do with that?

Comment: code is to remove any special characters from the input. User will not enter anything unusual but just to prevent that he doesnt access the file beyond the location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fileName.replaceAll("[/|\\|..|:|]","")
```

That regular expression is suspect - it will remove all occurrences of the characters `/`, `|`, `.` and `:`, which I doubt is what you had in mind.  Try something more like this instead:

```
fileName.replaceAll("/|\\\\|:|\\.\\.","")
```

Backslashes are a nightmare in Java regular expressions because you have to double them anyway in string literals, and then double them again in regular expressions (so you need `\\\\` to match a single backslash).  Also the dot on its own is special in regex (matching *any* single character) so to match a literal dot you need the regex `\.`, which means the Java string literal `\\.`

Comment: Yes the problem was with regex. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have problem removing double \ (because by looking at your expression that wouldn't work) you should change it to:

```
fileName = fileName.replaceAll("[/\\\\.:]","");
```

Comment: ".." removes the even the "." (Single dot)